# Input ignores CSS grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to build a CSS grid that has multiple columns with equals widths, which I can easily achieve with `grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);`. This works fine until I start putting `input` fields into one of the columns. Said column will then expand much further than 1/12 and I am not quite sure why or how to prevent it.

See this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mdc4bxLu/6/

Comment: Try adding `input { width: 100%; }`

Comment: That was it, thank you! I kept messing around with `display` and `min-width` ...

Comment: `input` elements has a default width set using its `size` attribute, which normally is `20` characters, hence one need to override it, where `width: 100%` is generally the best way.